# Fade text when using jquery .hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to swap text on hover, as follows:

```
$("#bottomMiddle").hover(function(){
        $("#rightHeading").text("CMS heading");
        $("#rightContent").text("CMS content");
        },function(){
        $("#rightHeading").text("This is the original heading");
        $("#rightContent").text("This is the original content");
});
```

This works but the effect is harsh and would like to fade the text in and out, I have tried using .fadeIn(); but had no success. Is there any way to use this hover swap and get it to fade at the same time?

Comment: As you are changing the text itself you can't fade out / in. You should try to use CSS3-Transitions or jQuery Animations for this on.

Comment: You can find effects from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by using callbacks.

This executes the `.text()` call when the `.fadeOut()` is complete, just before the `.fadeIn()`:

```js
$("#bottomMiddle").hover(function(){
        $("#rightHeading").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).text("Hello").fadeIn();
        });
        $("#rightContent").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).text("World").fadeIn();
        });
        },function(){
        $("#rightHeading").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).text("This is the original content").fadeIn();
        });
        $("#rightContent").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).text("This is the original content").fadeIn();
        });
});
```

```css
button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bottomMiddle">Button</button>
<div id="rightHeading">This is the original heading</div>
<div id="rightContent">This is the original content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with jQuery animations. Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/9b84hmtv/).

Your code could looks like this:

```
$("#bottomMiddle").hover(function(){
    $("#rightHeading").hide().text("CMS heading").fadeIn(200);
    $("#rightContent").hide().text("CMS content").fadeIn(200);
    },function(){
    $("#rightHeading").hide().text("This is the original heading").fadeIn(200);
    $("#rightContent").hide().text("This is the original content").fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: This answer is valid, but @Joel Almeida's answer shows how to use callbacks, so is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but really similar to Joel Almeida. I tried to better structure the code, so it is more obvious what is going on.

```js
var heading = $("#rightHeading")
var content = $("#rightContent")
var both = heading.add(content)
var animDuration = 300 // ms

var transition = function(headingText, contentText) {
  both.fadeOut(animDuration, function() {
    heading.text(headingText)
    content.text(contentText)
    both.fadeIn(animDuration)
  })
}

$("#bottomMiddle").hover(
  function() {
    transition('CMS heading', 'CMS content')
  },
  function() {
    transition('This is the original heading', 'This is the original content')
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottomMiddle">HOVER</div><br />
<div id="rightHeading">This is the original heading</div>
<div id="rightContent">This is the original content</div>
```